# db2 query with timestamp not triggered

Tags: db2

I'm trying to run a query in DB2 but it's giving me an error that Value in date,time or timestamp string not valid.

Basically, I'm trying to pull all records where the current date is between the date column + 7 days and the date column + 127 days. Or an easier way may be to say that the date column be within current_date - 127 days. I'm not sure why it's failing because it seems correct syntax wise

```
select
  framec,
  covr1c,
  colr1c,
  sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
from table
where date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2)) + 7 DAY <= CURRENT_DATE
AND date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2)) + 127 DAY >= CURRENT_DATE
group by framec,covr1c,colr1c;
```

Comment: There are functions in Db2 to convert string to date. What is the format of extd2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `extd2d` isn't an actual date datatype.

**So you could have spaces, or '20180219' in there...**

Personally, I'd change look at changing the table to use a date data type.  But that usually isn't quick or easy.

In which case I'd create a UDF for the conversion which returns NULL if the data is invalid. Or download Alan Campin's iDate from [here](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm)

You could then use the UDF to find the rows with bad data.

It's also better to convert the literal value, rather than the data in the table.  That way any indexes on the `extd2d` can be used...

```
select
  framec,
  covr1c,
  colr1c,
  sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
from table
where extd2d between char(ConvertToIDate(Current_date - 7 DAYS))
                 AND char(ConvertToIDate(Current_date - 127 DAYS))
group by framec,covr1c,colr1c;
```

`ConvertToIDate()` is a UDF included in Alan's iDate package.
`iDate()` => convert from Char/Num date to Date
`ConvertToIDate()` => convert from date to integer